# IntelliJ Project Build issue

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am receiving this error after completing my project setup in IntelliJ. If I build my project in Netbeans or Eclipse, I can compile just fine.

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Build process started. Classpath: /C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_51/lib/tools.jar;/C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4/lib/ecj-4.4.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(ILjava/util/concurrent/Executor;)V
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:97)
... 5 more
```

Comment: It's telling you there's no constructor found for the class: `io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup`, which likely means there's a jar file missing from your classpath.

Comment: @RyanJ it is in my libraries so I would assume it would be in the classpath for intellij. http://puu.sh/k5GGu/cbb25c032e.png